# I want to access variables i, j. k outside a triple nested for loop in java as initial position vectors for N body sim

Tags: java, arrays

For this code I generate position vectors for a 3d space.

I can print them out inside the nested loop but I need to be able to take the values outside the loop for further processing.

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int n = 5;
            int i;
            int j;
            int k;
    // Using a triple nested loop to generate i, j, k position vectors

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                        System.out.println("Particle has position vectors " + i + "i " + j + "j " + k + "k");
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Where your print is, call the function that needs to do the processing.  Outside the loop, the variables have no meaning.

Comment: So write the whole of the N body sim code in there?

Comment: or maybe you know a function I can put in there that can actually send the values elsewhere.

Comment: Take WHICH values outside the loop? Even if you declare the variables in the outer scope, when the loops end they will all have their maximum values (i.e. `n`, or in your case `5`) when the outer loop terminates.  Your question is unclear, you will have to show what you mean.

Comment: Right now you are calling a function for each element and passing it the values i,j and k.  That function is println.  Do the same thing for your N-body sim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
        // Using a triple nested loop to generate i, j, k position vectors

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    furtherProcessing(i, j, k);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void furtherProcessing(int i, int j, int k) {
        System.out.println("Particle has position vectors " + i + "i " + j + "j " + k + "k");
    }
}
```

Comment: That is brilliant Stewart.  It is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue. Outside of the for loops, any computation done inside isn't seen (unless it's saved to a variable for example). If you want to save the variable's new value, you're going to have to explicitly do so. Something like:

```
int i = 0;

for (int i2; i < 10; i++) {
     i += i2;
}
```

Comment: Just tried that.  Doesn't work.  Still out of scope.

Comment: Can you try calling a function that sets the variables in the loop? Or if they're vectors, simple adding them to a vector?

Answer (score 0):

Cast them into arrays, then you can use them anytime/anywhere. Otherwise, you will have to employ a lot of variables.

**UPDATE** 
I don't really know what exactly your variables would be, however, you can create an array of each of your variables to keep it stored for the future use.

```
int [] iarr = new  int[n] ;
int [] jarr = new int [n];
int [] karr = new int [n];       

     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            iarr[i] = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                jarr[j] = j;
                for ( int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    karr[k]= k;
                    //System.out.println("Particle has position vectors " +     i + "i " + j + "j " + k + "k");
                }
            }
        }      
  //Lets print them 
 System.out.println("i " + iarr[0] + "     " + "j "+ jarr[0]+ "      " + "k "+karr[0]);
 System.out.println("i " + iarr[1] + "     " + "j "+ jarr[1]+ "      " + "k "+karr[1]);
 System.out.println("i " + iarr[2] + "     " + "j "+ jarr[2]+ "      " + "k "+karr[2]);
 System.out.println("i " + iarr[3] + "     " + "j "+ jarr[3]+ "      " + "k "+karr[3]);
 System.out.println("i " + iarr[4] + "     " + "j "+ jarr[4]+ "      " + "k "+karr[4]);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 i 0     j 0      k 0
 i 1     j 1      k 1
 i 2     j 2      k 2
 i 3     j 3      k 3
 i 4     j 4      k 4
```

Comment: I don't know how.  I am totally new to programming.  I have very good mathematics behind me though so I was able to write an N body sim with 3 bodies where I actually declared the initial positions myself.  Now I want to be able to generate and use them from a 3d N*N*N grid in space.  Thats the reason I want to extract the values.  My code does generate them fine and I can print them all out.  Just can't use them.